# Conditional expectation of number of dice rolls

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-probability

I've been given the following problem and I'd like to get a better understanding of how to solve it.

A fair die is rolled successively. 
Let $X$ be the number of rolls needed to get a 6 
Let $Y$ be the number of rolls needed to get a 5.

Compute $E[X|Y=1]$ and $E[X|Y=5]$

Now, For the first one, I know I could do the following

$$\sum_{x=2}^\infty x(5/6)^{x-2}(1/6)$$

and arrive at the correct answer, $E[X|Y=1]=7$, because I already know I had one failure of $X$. However, this seems like a shortcut to me and I really want to understand how to do this by definition. So what I'm trying to evaluate is the following:

$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty x P(X=x|Y=1) = \sum_{x=1}^\infty x \frac{P(X=x,Y=1)}{P(Y=1)}$$

Now since $X$ and $Y$ are both geometric random variables, I know that $$P(Y=y) = (5/6)^{y-1}(1/6)$$ $$P(Y=1) = 1/6$$

However, what I'm not sure how to do is calculate $P(X=x,Y=1)$.

Comment: Ok, so then I'm just dealing with $\frac{P(X=x)}{P(Y=1)}$? But then $\sum_{x=1}^\infty x\frac{(5/6)^{x-1}(1/6)}{(1/6)} = \sum_{x=1}^\infty x(5/6)^{x-1} = 36$, which is not $7$

Comment: You are trying to compute the expectation for an *event*, which is not a variable. i.e, it is not a subset of the event space, it is a member. I don't think it makes sense.

Comment: Moreover, you are conditioning on something written as "$Y=5$" - but $Y$ is an event, according to your notation, not a random variable that could take a value. So that doesn't make sense either.

Comment: @audiFanatic what book\s are you using for studying Probability Theory?

Comment: Whoops, I'm sorry! I typed too fast...X and Y are random variables, not events. I'll fix that right now.

Comment: And I'm using `Introduction to Probability Models` by Sheldon Ross

Answer (score 1):

Note the following:

- For every $1\leqslant x\leqslant y$, $P(X\geqslant x\mid Y=y)=a^{x-1}$ where $a=4/5$.
- For every $x\geqslant y+1$, $P(X\geqslant x\mid Y=y)=a^{y-1}b^{x-y-1}$ where $b=5/6$.
- Finally, $E(X\mid Y=y)=\sum\limits_{x\geqslant1}P(X\geqslant x\mid Y=y)$.

Answer (score 0):

For $k=1,2,\dots$ denote $\mu_{k}=\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid Y=k\right)$.

Here $\mathbb{E}X=\frac{1}{6}\times1+\frac{5}{6}\times\left(1+\mathbb{E}X\right)$
leading to $\mathbb{E}X=6$ and $\mu_{1}=1+\mathbb{E}X=1+6=7$.

If $k>1$ then $\mu_{k}=\frac{1}{5}\times1+\frac{4}{5}\times\left(1+\mu_{k-1}\right)=1+\frac{4}{5}\mu_{k-1}$ leading to: $$\mu_{k}=5+2\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{k-1}$$

This expression for $\mu_k$ also covers the special case $k=1$. Note that under condition $Y=k>1$ the first roll *cannot* be a $5$ so that the probability that the first roll is a $6$ will be $\frac{1}{5}$. This corresponds with term $\frac{1}{5}\times1$. If the first roll is not a $6$ then we are back in the old situation with the following differences: we had exactly $1$ 'failure' and starting from here the number of rolls needed to get a $5$ has decreased with $1$. You could say that condition $Y=k$ has become condition $Y=k-1$ in the new situation. This corresponds with term $\frac{4}{5}\times\left(1+\mu_{k-1}\right)$

---

**addendum focused on comments**

We have $\mu_{1}=7$ and $\mu_{k}=1+\frac{4}{5}\mu_{k-1}$. In order
to find a closed form for $\mu_{k}$ it is a good custom to have a
look at $\mu_{k}$ for - let's say $k=1,2,3,4$. Quite often a pattern
can be discovered. We find:

$\mu_{1}=7$

$\mu_{2}=1+\frac{4}{5}\times7$

$\mu_{3}=1+\frac{4}{5}\left(1+\frac{4}{5}\times7\right)=1+\frac{4}{5}+\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{2}\times7$

$\mu_{4}=1+\frac{4}{5}\left(1+\frac{4}{5}+\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{2}\times7\right)=1+\frac{4}{5}+\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{3}\times7$

Well, doesn't this smell like: $$\mu_{k}=1+\frac{4}{5}+\cdots+\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{k-2}+\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{k-1}\times7$$?
Making use of the wellknown rule $1+r^{1}+\cdots+r^{n-1}=\frac{1-r^{n}}{1-r}$
we can find an expression for $\mu_{k}$. If you have found such an
expression then check whether it satisfies the conditions $\mu_{1}=7$
and $\mu_{k}=1+\frac{4}{5}\mu_{k-1}$. There is only one sequence
$\left(\mu_{k}\right)$ that satisfies these conditions, so you are
ready if it does.

Concerning the calculation of $\mathbb{E}X$ denote the outcome of
the first roll by $D$. Then $\mathbb{E}X=\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid D=6\right)P\left[D=6\right]+\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid D\neq6\right)P\left[D\neq6\right]$.
Here $P\left[D=6\right]=\frac{1}{6}$ and $\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid D=6\right)=1$
(since under this condition only one roll is needed to get a $6$).
If $D\neq6$ then you land in the same situation with the only difference
that there was exactly one 'failure'. That's why $\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid D\neq6\right)=1+\mathbb{E}X$.
This leads to $\mathbb{E}X=\frac{1}{6}\times1+\frac{5}{6}\times\left(1+\mathbb{E}X\right)$.

**remark**

Very often a proof based on conditionals excels in simplicity and elegance. Try to get hold of that 'technique' and ask questions as: 'what has changed after one roll (or other sort of thing)?'.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how you came up with that expression for $\mu_k$? It does work, but I don't really understand where you got it from

Comment: Now that I'm looking at it again, I'm having a harder time understanding where $EX$ came from than where $\mu_k$ came from. The recursive nature if $EX$ is hard to grapple

Comment: @audiFanatic I have added some things. I hope it is clear now.